# PowerShell Rename or Delete Thumbs.db Files

Tags: windows, powershell, operating-system, system

I am dealing with the Windows bug where you are unable to delete Thumbs.db, as Windows thinks they are "open".

Firstly, I am aware of the possibility of using regedit to allow these to be deleted, but I do not own the network folder so am unable to access the server to do this. However if it helps anyone here is how you would do that:

```
 add a new "Explorer" Registry path:

 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\

 and then add a DWORD entry called "DisableThumbsDBOnNetworkFolders", and set it to 1.
```

I have found that if I manually rename the Thumbs.db to say "ThisSucks.db" then I can delete the file. I have a ton of these folders with Thumbs in them so I want to write a PS script to rename all of them, or bonus delete.

When I gather the thumbs into a collection, I see the Write-Host print for each file, but when I try to rename I am getting "Cannot rename because file does not exist".

```
[System.Object[]] $directory = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter "*.db" -Force -Recurse;

foreach($file in $directory){
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Found Thumb files";
    Rename-Item $file "StupidFile.db";
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Rename-Item` takes the Path as a string, and implicitly casting $file, which is a `[System.Io.FileInfo]`, to a string turns it into the short name, not the full path. So you're trying to rename files in subfolders without telling rename-item where the files are, just giving it the filename. `Rename-Item $file.FullName "stupidfile.db"`

Comment: Are you able to run `gpedit.msc`? https://mikebeach.org/2013/01/05/disable-thumbs-db-creation-on-network-drives-in-windows/

Comment: Thanks @TessellatingHeckler for pointing this out. I did not realize this was happening!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TessellatingHeckler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478656/tessellatingheckler) provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

Perhaps surprisingly, the **`[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances returned by `Get-ChildItem` bind to `Rename-Item`'s `-Path` parameter as *strings* when passed as *direct argument***, and, in a string context, **a `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instance expands to its *mere filename*, not the *full path***.

Therefore, unless a `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instance happens to refer to a file in the *current* directory, `Rename-Item` won't find it.

**Binding the `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances via the *pipeline* is *not* subject to this pitfall** (the `.PSPath` property is used for binding to `-Path`), so you can use the following:

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*.db' -Force -Recurse |
   Rename-Item -NewName 'StupidFile.sb' -WhatIf
```

Note the `-WhatIf` switch, which *previews* the renaming operations. Remove this switch to perform the actual renaming.

---

A note on your first statement, `[System.Object[]] $directory = Get-ChildItem ...`:

Rather than casting to `[System.Object[]]`, you can use **`@()`, the array subexpression operator**, to ensure that a command's output is treated as an array, even if it returns only a single item (or none):

```
$directory = @(Get-ChildItem ...)
```

That said, on **PSv3+** this is typically not necessary, because **any *scalar* value can also be used as if it were an *array***; e.g.:

```
> $scalar = 'a single value'

# Treat $scalar as a collection:

# A scalar as a collection by definition has count 1.
> $scalar.Count
1  

# Enumerate the scalar in a foreach loop.
> foreach ($itm in $scalar) { "[$itm]" }
[a single value]

# Process the scalar in a pipeline using the ForEach-Object cmdlet.
> $scalar | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }
[a single value]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your amazingly detailed response. It was enlightening as much as it was useful!